# Android AdMob Timed out

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add some Admob ads into my application. So far I've made the following code into the `onCreate` method.

```
    long previousAdShown = this.prefs.getLong("last_ad_shown", 0);
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    if (Constants.ADMOB_ENABLE && (previousAdShown < now - Constants.ADMOB_INTERVAL))
    {
        Log.e("ADMOB", "Load ADMOB");
        // Load ad view
        this.adView = new InterstitialAd(this);
        this.adView.setAdUnitId(Constants.ADMOB_ID);
        AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequest.addTestDevice("31090DB31C8059FC6EF0FDA2XXXXXXXX");

        this.adView.loadAd(adRequest.build());

        // Update timer
        this.prefs.edit().putLong("last_ad_shown", now).commit();
    }
```

Which is supposed to pre-load the ads.

Then, in my Menu I got something like that:

```
    this.menu_me_feed_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (adView != null && adView.isLoaded())
            {
                adView.show();
                adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed()
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LeftMenu.this.activity, UserFeedActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("isForUser", false);
                        LeftMenu.this.activity.startActivity(intent);
                        LeftMenu.this.activity.finish();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LeftMenu.this.activity, UserFeedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isForUser", false);
                LeftMenu.this.activity.startActivity(intent);
                LeftMenu.this.activity.finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Which basically displays the ads if it was previously loaded.

I got two error:

- `03-26 20:44:37.437: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(28151): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.`
  Which, according to the Admob doc, is not a blocking error.
- `03-26 20:44:59.242: W/Ads(28151): Timed out waiting for ad response.
  03-26 20:44:59.252: W/dalvikvm(28151): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
  03-26 20:44:59.257: W/Ads(28151): Failed to load ad: 2`

I don't understand why I got those errors as my `AdUnitId` is correct.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is benign and can be ignored.

The 2nd suggests that you didn't have a good network connection, or that the Admob server was under extreme load (unlikely). Make sure you have a good net connection and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, my connection was too slow to retrieve the ads in time. Trying again this morning, solved my problem.